# Using Compojure, Hiccup and Ring to upload MULTIPLE files

Tags: clojure, ring

This is really a rip off of [Using Compojure, Hiccup and Ring to upload a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712645/using-compojure-hiccup-and-ring-to-upload-a-file)

If there is a multiple tag:

```
<form action="/file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="file" type="file" size="20" multiple/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

How would one go about getting the values of all the files using ring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a test project and checked what sort of data the request map contains when arriving to the back-end when submitting multiple files. Below is a part of the request map:

```
{:multipart-params {"submit" submit,
                    "file" [{:size 439,
                             :tempfile #<File /tmp/ring-multipart-5216436296043515206.tmp>,
                             :content-type application/javascript,
                             :filename bar.js}
                            {:size 24,
                             :tempfile #<File /tmp/ring-multipart-3573753728611312574.tmp>,
                             :content-type application/octet-stream,
                             :filename foo.md}], ...}
```

Seems that `(get-in request [:multipart-params "file"])` would give you a vector of the uploaded files, containing information on what their original file names and types were and where they are temporarily stored. According to [Ring's documentation](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/File-Uploads) the files will be stored for one hour.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using noir and I think this part doesn't get passed. I'll investigate further!