# Multiple Files Upload: Clojure Rest Service

Tags: angularjs, rest, clojure, ring

I want to upload multiple file from angularJS to Clojure Rest service. I have studied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163010/using-compojure-hiccup-and-ring-to-upload-multiple-files) answer but it is not for angularJS and Clojure Rest Service therefore, I cannot understand how to implement it. Please provide an example to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried apart from reading the linked answer? Where exactly are you getting stuck? By saying "Please provide a practical example to this problem." it sounds like you're simply asking for someone to implement a solution for you, which isn't really how this site works.

Comment: Thank you @madstap . In the "linked answer" the request map is written in clojure script which can easily get in server-side clojure. But I want to send files array from angularJS and get in clojure rest service. I have no idea how to send and receive multiple files in this situation. In the light of your comments I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your question really has two parts:

1. How to upload multiple files from AngularJS to the server - I believe you can find lots of online help on this; look here e.g. [Angularjs how to upload multipart form data and a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443246/angularjs-how-to-upload-multipart-form-data-and-a-file)
2. How to process multipart uploads on Clojure server side - this is something that's covered by the SO question you linked in your description: [Using Compojure, Hiccup and Ring to upload MULTIPLE files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163010/using-compojure-hiccup-and-ring-to-upload-multiple-files)